# Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

I am having a problem while configuring a hibernate application. Please could you help me with this. I searched a whole lot of forums but could not find the solution. I know this question has been asked in previously, but the solution didn't work for me.

Here is my hibernate.config file

```
<!--
  ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
  ~
  ~ License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
  ~ See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
  -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">manoj</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">manoj$123</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.manoj.java.hibernate.UserDetails"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And here is my tnsnames.ora file

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

And here is my listener.ora file

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

I added the SID Desc of XE in listener.ora which if I remove, then also it was not working.

and here is my exception log

```
Apr 22, 2017 11:40:01 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
Apr 22, 2017 11:40:01 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Apr 22, 2017 11:40:02 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Apr 22, 2017 11:40:02 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Apr 22, 2017 11:40:02 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521:orcl]
Apr 22, 2017 11:40:02 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=manoj, password=****}
Apr 22, 2017 11:40:02 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Apr 22, 2017 11:40:02 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at com.manoj.java.session.HibernateSession.main(HibernateSession.java:15)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
    ... 34 more
```

Please if somebody could guide me, how can I get this thing right?

This question was marked duplicate, but i am not finding the answer still, so I am reposting this question.

Comment: Have you tried with `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe` instead (semicolon vs slash)?

Comment: yup.. i have tried it earlier.

Comment: Okay, the problem might be that you're declaring `SERVICE NAME` instead of `SID` in tnsnames.ora. That requires a different URL syntax: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE`

Comment: No Sir,  The problem still persists. I changed the url as you said

Comment: Then you could still try to change tnsnames.ora from `SERVICE NAME = XE` to `SID = XE` and try my first URL suggestion.

Comment: I changed the service name to SID and I replaced the : before XE, still the result is same. it is refusing to connect. I know it is frustating but sir  could you please suggest me what to do next. I can give you whatever inputs you need for this

Comment: Did you restart Oracle and the TNSListener services after changing tnsnames.ora?

Comment: I restarted both the services, and it is still giving the same error

Comment: I guess the problem was with my eclipse. I created a new workspace in eclipse Mars and changed the included the ojdbc-11.2.0.3 jar in my maven project with all the necessary hibernate jars and now it is working. Earlier I was using eclipse indigo.